# does Power BI gateway data source ignore credentials used to create dataset?

Tags: powerbi

I have a Power BI workbook that I have created in Desktop.  It sources from a SQL Server database.  I can access this database with account x.  My Azure tenant admin has created a data source for this database in our gateway (within the Power BI service), and I have access to this gateway.  The admin supplied account y in connecting to this data source.  How does this work when I go to refresh the dataset that this workbook creates when I publish it to the service?  That is, when I schedule a refresh on the dataset, will it dial into the SQL Server database using account y provided in the data source definition (virtually ignoring / dropping account x's credentials)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep. That's exactly how it works.  The automated refresh will use account 'Y.'

Data sources that have been deployed to some hosted location will almost always disregard the credentials used to create the dataset and instead use credentials that are specifically supplied for the refresh.  These 'service' accounts will typically have different rules about password resets, have the lowest appropriate levels of access, and be under the prevue of system administrators rather than report authors.  Its a very standard practice.  It protects against misuse, error, loss of accounts, and segregates actual user activity from automated behaviors in the logs.

However, it is a little odd to me that your admin 'created the datasource' -- is that correct? Or did the admin just wire up the gateway to the datasource that was deployed when you published?

If you want to use a datasource that is already published, then you need to connect to that datasource from PowerBI desktop.  Otherwise you'll be pushing out something new that has nothing to do with the resources that your admin created.

Comment: The admin already created the data source (with account y specified).  I'm not sure what the proper procedure should be.  Should I first publish a dataset, and then wait for my admin to create the data source to correspond with my dataset?  Or, do I hold off on publishing until I know that my admin has created the appropriate data source, given that I can't refresh until it's created anyways?  And, should I be developing using (service) account y rather than account x (in case they have different levels of access)?

Comment: Well, if the admin put that datasource out there and it has everything you need, then you might as well go ahead and use it (I would think).  Never wrong to shoot the admin an email and confirm tho.  But after that you can connect directly to the admin's dataset from PowerBI Desktop, develop your report, and publish.  It should zip right out there and use the exiting datasource and that's all there is to it.  You'll be refreshing your report from the datasource, and it will be refreshing from the underlying databases using account y.

Comment: Because a dataset is just a subset of the data source itself, what if I want to create other reports on the same data source, but not necessarily the same dataset?  Wouldn't I have to develop the report (in Desktop) from the SQL Server DB, which creates another dataset when published, and tell that new dataset to use the same data source?

Comment: That's one way to do it.  Or you can request for the dataset owner to load more data.  Ultimately it's a question of where do you want your costs to be - lots of redundant datasets from every report writer deploying their own variations, or the procedural red tape of requesting the existing dataset owners expand their dataset to accommodate your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much!  This is very helpful information.

Comment: I have a similar problem and no solution so far https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68875489/power-bi-service-ignores-the-dataset-s-credentials-to-the-data-source In case anyone can help