# Power BI Service ignores the dataset’s credentials to the data source

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

Scenario: On-premises SQL Server, with Gateway, having implemented RLS and two users: masterUser (access to all) and userOne (access to a limited set of rows).

In PBI Desktop, I created the following Direct Query datasets,

- datasetMaster using masterUser’s credentials.
- datasetUserOne using userOne’s credentials.

From PBI Desktop, both work fine: reports based on datasetMaster retrieve all rows; the ones based on datasetUserOne retrieve only the filtered rows.

- Uploaded datasetMaster to Power BI service: works well, all rows retrieved.
- Uploaded datasetUserOne to Power BI service: WRONG retrieves all rows as masterUser, presumably using the same credentials.

**How can I force each dataset to use its credentials**?

This already seemed to be a problem back in 2018 [Problem with two dataset of same database but different user access](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/Problem-with-two-dataset-of-same-database-but-different-user/td-p/414672)

The final scenario in case it matters: I need a Power BI single-tenant embedded workspace-based isolation (to allow SaaS users to create their reports) with direct query  (near real-time updates), each workspace accessing only its tenant’s data (RLS on the data source)

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Are you using RLS in Power BI? If so, you have to do more than just upload the dataset to the PBI service, you also have to manage security for it. See [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-rls#manage-security-on-your-model) for more details.

Comment: In case anyone bumps into this same problem, the solution provided by [Greg_Dekler](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/313) is [Multiple data source definitions on the On-premises data gateway for the same data source](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/multiple-data-source-definitions-on-the-on-premises-data-gateway-for-the-same-data-source/) For the sake of completeness, the alternative I found and tested was using query parameters based on [Change the Source of Power BI Datasets Dynamically Using Power Query Parameters](https://radacad.com/change-the-source-

Comment: No, I'm using RLS in SQL Server. Not sure, but I think that's the only way to work with DirectQuery if you need near-real-time data. I still have to test that out.